# Output from a Neural Network model

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have created a couple of models in MATLAB Neural Network Toolbox with a hundred of inputs and 10 outputs that correspond to different classes. At the end, NN gives a plot regarding a performance which is a number. What does this measure correspond to? Is it sum of errors from each outputs?

How can I know if NN is classifying well?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The performance metric depends on the performance function set in the neural network toolbox parameters.  For instance, if performFcn is 'mse' then it will use the mean square error as the performance metric.  See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/analyze-neural-network-performance-after-training.html for more information on how Matlab sets these parameters.  In general, when using anything like Neural Networks, it is important to understand what it is trying to optimise, and how, to avoid problems such as overfitting.  There are a lot of parameters to tune!

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284971/training-neural-network-tips?rq=1) for more detailed information